# Function Parameter Not Carrying Value in JQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, .net, jquery-selectors

The RowIndex variable in this function doesn't seem to carry it's value when used in the gridview selector:

```
       function selectRow(RowIndex) {
        $("#<%= gvwShipments.ClientID %> tr:eq(RowIndex)").css('background-color', '#FFFF99');
       }
```

The header row, being the first row in the gridiview, is always being selected. I'm sure this is a syntax issue, how do you get the selector to recognize the RowIndex value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's syntax issue, this should work:

```
function selectRow(RowIndex) {
     $("#<%= gvwShipments.ClientID %> tr:eq(" + RowIndex + ")").css('background-color', '#FFFF99');
}
```